# If the atomic number is # of protons, why does emission of a beta (electron) particle increase the atomic number?

Tags: electrons, protons

> Atomic number: the number of protons in the nucleus of an atom, which is characteristic of a chemical element and determines its place in the periodic table.

Beta emission:

$$\ce{^14_6C -> ^14_7N + ^0_{-1}\beta}$$

**Why does emission of an electron increase the atomic number, when the atomic number is the number of protons, not electrons?**

Comment: In a beta decay a proton may change into a neutron. Or a neutron may change into a proton. http://www2.lbl.gov/abc/wallchart/chapters/03/2.html

Comment: Maybe you are confusing it with alpha decay?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It makes sense now. I forgot the part about a neutron changing into a proton. I thought the change in number of protons had something to do with a proton being a + and an electron being a -, rather than a loss of an electron converting a neutron into a +.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

During beta particle emission one neutron is converted into proton and electron, to balance charge and electron can't remain inside the nucleus hence emitted from the nucleus.